# How do I add object to NSMutableDictionary with key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a plist. I want add the elememts from that plist to a mutable dictionary. First I check the user name in the plist, and my current name are same or not. If it is same, then I want to add all value to that dictionary rom plist, and also assign the same key:

```
 for(int i=0;i<[displayList count];i++)
    {
        if([[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:user])
        {
            [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"ID"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ID"];
            [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
            [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"Place"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Place"];
          [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"username"];
            

        }
    }
```

**[displayList count] this value is 7 so each value replacing 6 times ,and am getting only final values** I want every values matching to user name I that mutabledictionary.

Comment: so what's the problem here?  hopefully "`finalBooks`" is your "`NSMutableDictionary`", yes?

Comment: yes but [displayList count] this value is 7 so each value replacing 6 times ,and am getting only final values

Comment: @mango this is because you are setting (*replacing*) values of dictionary against same keys in every iteration, thats why you only get final values.

Comment: Break at least the first of those lines into 3 separate lines so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should create array of dictionary. Just add your finalBooks dictionary to NSMutableArray like this

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

(int i=0;i<[displayList count];i++)
{
    if([[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:user])
    {
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"ID"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ID"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"Place"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Place"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"username"];

        [finalArray addObject:finalBooks];
    }
}
```

And you will get array of dictionary. Good Luck !!

Comment: Shouldn't you use -objectForKey:/-setObject:forKey:?

Answer (score 3):

setValue method in a NSMutableDictionary replaces the value if the key is same. So what you can do is either use NSMutableDictionary of arrays or dictionaries.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

(int i=0;i<[displayList count];i++)
{
    if([[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:user])
    {
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"ID"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"ID"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"Place"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Place"];
        [finalBooks setValue:[[data valueForKey:@"username"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"username"];

        [userDictionary setObject:finalBooks forKey:user];
    }
}
```

If you want everything in one dictionary, I suggest you use a unique key such as `NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID+%@",username],...[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username+%@",username]`

But it looks messy :)